# list procedure in Scheme

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

I am studying for an exam right now but I am not sure if I understood the `list` procedure in Scheme. I know that it can be used for creating list variables like `(define x (list 'a 'b 'c))`. However I saw another usage of it in procedure creation:

```
1 ]=> (define foo3
           (lambda (b lst)
                (if b
                    (car lst)
                    (cadr lst)
                )
           )
      )
;Value: foo3

1 ]=> (foo3 #f ’(a b))
;Value: b

1 ]=> ((foo3 #t (list cdr car)) ’(a b c))
;Value: (b c)
```

What does the **(list cdr car)** mean? (I know what `cdr` and `car` means in terms of referencing first and rest of the list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code, `(list cdr car)` is just a list of procedures. `foo3` will select one procedure from that list, according to the passed parameter `b`. In the second example, this snippet:

```
(foo3 #t (list cdr car))
```

... Will return `cdr` because the first parameter was `#t`, so in the end we're just evaluating this:

```
(cdr '(a b c))
=> '(b c)
```

Comment: Ow, I see. I am still thinking the way that list are basically arrays in C. I didn't think that we can store procedures in it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, that's one of the nice things in functional programming languages: procedures are just like any other data type, and you can pass them around as parameters, return them from other procedures, store them in data structures, etc.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can store functions in C arrays too, it's just not very common because C's functions are such a hassle to create.